# Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.1) classpath

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

So my flutter android app runs fine with firebase google services 4.0.1, but when I add the dependancy "firebase_auth" to pubspec.yaml, it produces this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
>
> Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

The package is gotten correctly in the pubspec.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add to app level build.gradle.

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
```

Good Luck dear.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the problem which always occurred when I tried to depend on the 'firebase_auth' package.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your android/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'android.arch.lifecycle'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "1.1.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```